# Selecting an element where selector finds in a specific class of element

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure of div tags and each div tag has multiple classes like :-

```
<div>

     <div class="jsh-a_train_hotel_amsterdam info js-multiple"></div>

     <div class="jsh-info info js-multiple"></div>

     <div class="jsh-myinfo info js-single"></div>

</div>
```

Now I want to find div tags which have class name starting with "jsh-" and also the class that starts with "jsh-" should have a substring "info" in it.

So the result should be the following :-

```
<div class="jsh-info info js-multiple"></div>
<div class="jsh-myinfo info js-single"></div>
```

(Reason: Because  the above 2 div tags have classes jsh-info and jsh-myinfo which satisfies the condition that the element class name should have "jsh-" and the substring in the "jsh-" class name value should have string "info" in it)

Comment: review your question there is no desc in the like sections

Comment: Your markup is missing closing divs.

Comment: Just reformatted and the section is now visible..

Comment: I think you should rethink your selecting scenario. Use one class to select the `divs` for one scenario, e.g. `jsh-select` and use one function to distinct its purpose, e.g. `hasClass("info")`. The given answers are correct but your requirements make it far to irregular to create a standard ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var elems = $('div[class^="jsh"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('class').match(/jsh[^ ]info/)
});
```

Or better use following as `jsh-info` can occur anywhere in `class` attribute value

```
var elems = $('div[class*="jsh"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('class').match(/\s*jsh[^ ]info/)
});
```

### Update

A you don't need to apply any jquery functions on the elements inside `filter()`, converting a DOM element to a jQuery object is not needed. So you can use

```
return this.className.match(/\s*jsh[^ ]*info/)
```

instead of

```
return $(this).attr('class').match(/\s*jsh[^ ]info/)
```

### Update 2

If you don't want to hardcode `info` and want to replace it with a variable, you can do as follows

```
var theVar = 'info';
$('div[class*="jsh"]').filter(function () {
    return this.className.match(new RegExp('jsh[^ ]*' + theVar, 'gi'))
})
```

Comment: Ejay, this really seems promising, and since i am not too much expert in regex, can you please tell will it also find div with class "jsh-ab_info_bye"?

Comment: it does, you can test it with various combinations :)

Comment: How can this regex match `jsh-myinfo`?

Comment: the `[^ ]*` part in `jsh[^ ]*info` means `zero or more characters that are not a space`. So `jsh[^ ]*info` will match `jshinfo`, `jsh-info`, `jsh-myinfo`, `jsh-ab_info`, and `jsh_anything_can_be_here_except_space_info`. You can read more about this in detail on following MDN Page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Ejay Then can I ask you why only `div2` in this example has red color: http://jsfiddle.net/TaK8f/

Comment: that's because `jsh[^ ]info` will only match one character between `jsh` and `info`, i.e., `jsh-info` in your case. But I can also match `jshAinfo`, `jshBinfo`,`jsh_info`, `jshXinfo` etc. **Note that `jsh[^ ]info` and `jsh[^ ]*info` are different**

Comment: Ejay, can you please add one more thing..if i want to make the string "info" above dynamic i.e it will be a variable filled dynamically, then what will we need to change in regular expression to take a varialbe in place of hardcoded string ("info" in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `$('div[class^="jsh-"]').filter('div[class*="info"]')`  the first selector is `start with` the second is `contains`.

Comment: This will not work because it will select first div tag too as first div tag has class that start with "jsh-" and it also has a separate class "info", which is not what i require. I want to select element which has class that starts with "jsh-" and the same class that starts with "jsh-" should have a substring "info" like "jsh-myinfo".

Comment: $('div[class^="jsh-"]').filter('div[class*="info"]').not('.info') but you must be aware that this kind of selector is computationally heavy

Comment: Cecilia, I think this will also not work as ".not('.info')"  will filter out all the divs which have "info" class, thus there will be no divs in result.